# Replit: Why am I getting PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR for my Django project?

Tags: django, browser, ide, replit

I run a Django repl within Replit. However, I often cannot access the browser preview of my project because of a "PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR" in Firefox.

I also tried using Brave and Chromium, but no luck with them either: they showed an "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" error.

When I reached out to Replit Support, they said, "This looks like a problem that someone in our community can help with."

Can any of you help?